# does solaris LDOM require seperate license

Tags: solaris

we are planning to install 5-6 LDOMS on Sun server T5240, as the server is purchased from Sun so the OS license is free. but does creating many LDOMS require some additional license?

please revert back soon

Comment: You're planning to install the proprietary version of Solaris in the LDOMS?

Comment: Yes, Solaris 10 would be installed on each LDOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pre-Oracle days, there was no need for extra licensing (costs).  AFAIK, this hasn't changed since the acquisition.